# By clicking a button, that's on a infowindow of a specific marker, I want the marker to change color depending on which button I click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm working on a view of the ASP.NET, using mvc. I using google maps with different markers. Each of those markers have their own infowindows that have 3 buttons each. By clicking a specific button I want the marker to change color. How can I do that?

I have already tried using document.getElementById and using the addEventListner. I also tried to program the button by using the onclick function.

```
        var locations = [
            ["Recusado", "13/02/2019", 38.776816, -9.441833, 335, "foto.jpg", ],
            ["Aceite", "15/08/2019",38.817562, -8.941728, 36, "foto.jpg"],
            ["Em avaliação", "20/07/2019",38.487978, -9.004425, 90,"foto.jpg"],
            ["Concluído", "01/07/2019",37.045804, -8.898041, 12, "foto.jpg"]

        ];



 var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({});





        function setMarkers(map) {

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var fire = locations[i];
                var marker ;

                var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                    '<p>Fotografias:' + fire[5] + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Avaliação:' + fire[0] + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Data:' + fire[1] + '</p></br>' +
                    '<button id="aceite">Aceite</button>' +
                    '<button>Recusado</button>' +
                    '<button> Em avaliação</button>' +
                    '<button> Concluído</button>' +
                    '</div>';
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString });







                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: { lat: fire[2], lng: fire[3] },
                        map: map,
                        info: contentString,
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'

                    });



                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                    infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
                    infoWindow.open(map, this);

                });

            }
        }
```

The buttons are represented in the variable contentString, and when I click the button with the id "Aceite", I want to change the color of the marker to green.

Attempt to change the marker to green:

```
<button id="aceite" onclick="state(marker)">Aceite</button> 

function state(marker){ 
  marker.setIcon('google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
}
```

Comment: Did you check the link I posted above? You can use `addEventListener` but add it from within the `domready` event of the Infowindow.

Comment: but I have multiple markers, and when I add that it only changes the color of the last marker add instead of the marker clicked

Comment: Implement what you said you have implemented, and open a new question that includes a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried and how you implemented it. "*it only changes the color of the last marker*" sounds like you might need to use a [closure](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure) but nobody can tell for sure without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest would be to add the click listener function when you open the InfoWindow (when you know what marker it is associated with).

1. Add the click listener to the button when the `domready` event of the InfoWindow fires (and it has been added to the DOM):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("aceite"), 'click', function(e) {
    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
  })
});
```

2. Use function closure on the marker in the marker click listener (`this` references the marker in the click event listener function, but not in the InfoWindow domready event listener, save it so you can use it there):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  var marker = this;
  infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
  google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("aceite"), 'click', function(e) {
      marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
    })
  });
  infoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mvpcbqgx/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map after changing two marker icons green]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  setMarkers(map);
}
var locations = [
  ["Recusado", "13/02/2019", 38.776816, -9.441833, 335, "foto.jpg", ],
  ["Aceite", "15/08/2019", 38.817562, -8.941728, 36, "foto.jpg"],
  ["Em avaliação", "20/07/2019", 38.487978, -9.004425, 90, "foto.jpg"],
  ["Concluído", "01/07/2019", 37.045804, -8.898041, 12, "foto.jpg"]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var fire = locations[i];
    var marker;

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
      '<div id="siteNotice">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div id="bodyContent">' +
      '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
      '<p>Fotografias:' + fire[5] + '</p>' +
      '<p>Avaliação:' + fire[0] + '</p>' +
      '<p>Data:' + fire[1] + '</p></br>' +
      '<button id="aceite">Aceite</button>' +
      '<button>Recusado</button>' +
      '<button> Em avaliação</button>' +
      '<button> Concluído</button>' +
      '</div>';
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: fire[2],
        lng: fire[3]
      },
      map: map,
      info: contentString,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      var marker = this;
      infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
      google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("aceite"), 'click', function(e) {
          marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
        })
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```