# how to change map marker color on click button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, button, google-maps-markers

in `infowindow.setContent` i have button i want to change marker color button on click i tried this code

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][3] + " <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm map-checked-box mr-1' onclick='myFunction();' data-id='"+ locations[i][3] +"'>Print</button> ");
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i ));
    }
    function myFunction() {
  infowindow.setContent('<div style="background-color: green">' + locations[i][0] + locations[i][3] + "</div>");
}
```

**i am calling myfunction() but it does not work in this line** i think i am misiing locations in function

```
infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][3] + " <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm map-checked-box mr-1' onclick='myFunction();' data-id='"+ locations[i][3] +"'>Print</button> ");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change google map marker icon when clicking button inside infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352007/change-google-map-marker-icon-when-clicking-button-inside-infowindow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [By clicking a button, that's on a infowindow of a specific marker, I want the marker to change color depending on which button I click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57556534/by-clicking-a-button-thats-on-a-infowindow-of-a-specific-marker-i-want-the-ma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the color of a marker through CSS because markers are images.
You will have to set a new image to the existing marker to get an effect of the changed marker color.

General steps would be :

1. Store the marker in a variable that is available later in `myFunction`.
2. Update the marker image using `setIcon(urlToNewImage)`

[Here is an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj2ptzfa/1/). Click on the change button to see the effect.

[Refer to this link](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/) for a list of icons available online.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by

```
function state(marker){ 
  marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange.png');
}
```